PowerApps Expression for button using on select function to make some fields read only
I need to modify a SharePoint list form with PowerApps so that I can have one user (user1) enter information in form fields, submit their input to the list and then have that information available for read only when a second user opens the form to edit additional fields. My initial thought would be to use a button to submit the data and make the fields that USER1 read only. I just don't know how to do that or what expressions to use where....as I am new to PowerApps. So I literally need a step by step.
I'm experimenting with buttons, but am open to any method such as toggles etc.

To make field disable/editable you need to set the DisplayMode property of Datacards with the formula, example is shown in below screenshot.

